# Android permission check in more than one function

Tags: android, permissions, location

I need to use methods of `LocationManager` object, which requires location permission, in more than one function. I am wondering if I make a check for location permissions in every method that require to do so, user will get a few request to accept permission for location.

Is there a way to check for permission in one particular place instead of asking for it in every single place?

Comment: You just need to get the permission once. Once you get it it will work everywhere unless the user manually revoke it :)

Comment: you can check permition in main activity and if is permited do nothing else ask user to allow, no need to check in all function.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira Will it be enough to check location permission once in main activity and then in every method that require permission handle a potential SecurityException?

Comment: @wkurek no, if location permition is checked correctly you dont have exceptions.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira So where I should place the check for location permissions  when I use class that does not belong to neither activity nor fragment to achieve that?

Comment: Its not possible to check permition in neither activity nor fragment you need one activity to check permitions

Comment: @BrunoFerreira Yes, you are right but I am develiping my app in AndroidStudio and even if i check for location permission before using class in context of activity/fragment it report about need to check permission

Comment: Because the class is before the context, why you dont try to put the check permition in the context of activity/fragment?

Comment: @wkurek Can you add your code to better show what can you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check wherever you would like; it is best practice to check if the permission is enabled before you use it, that means wherever you use even if it is multiple times.

This is because the user could turn off locations at any point so it is safe to do the checks before you need them.